# Rails console - is there a safe mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to use `rails console` in production system but with limited capabilities?

Let's say, one doesn't want to accidentally call a `model.delete_all` in production while inspecting a bug or debugging a production issue.

Answer (score 4):

`rails console --sandbox` should revert all changes once you close the console, but it does not prevent you from running `delete_all` in the first place.